# split php string into chunks of varying length

Tags: php, arrays, string, split

I am looking for ways to split a string into an array, sort of `str_split()`, where the chunks are all of different sizes.

I could do that by looping through the string with a bunch of `substr()`, but that looks neither elegant nor efficient. Is there a function that accept a string and an array, like (`1, 18, 32, 41, 108, 125, 137, 152, 161`), and yields an array of appropriately chopped string pieces?

Explode is inappropriate because the chunks are delimited by varying numbers of white spaces.

Comment: Did you check php explode() function?

Comment: Jirka: explode will not do, because of the above (my edit)

Comment: An example for this is anything from the cms.gov website such as icd10 codes or NCCI codes. They are all fixed length columns of data. I assume because the government is stuck in 1940s and hasn't heard about the invention of the CSV format let alone xml or json. https://www.cms.gov/Medicare/Coding/ICD10/2019-ICD-10-PCS.html

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is nothing in PHP that will do that for you (it's a bit specific). So as radashk just siad, you just have to write a function

```
function getParts($string, $positions){
    $parts = array();

    foreach ($positions as $position){
        $parts[] = substr($string, 0, $position);
        $string = substr($string, $position);
    }

    return $parts;
}
```

Something like that. You can then use it wherever you like, so it's clean:

```
$parts = getParts('some string', array(1, ... 161));
```

If you really wanted to, you could implode it into a regular expression:

```
^.{1}.{18} <lots more> .{161}$
```

would match what you wanted.

Answer (score 5):

I would use [unpack](http://php.net/unpack)():

```
$str = "?ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890....";
$array = unpack("a1first/a26second/a10third/a*rest",$str);
print_r($array);
```

This returns:

```
Array
(
    [first] => ?
    [second] => ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ
    [third] => 1234567890
    [rest] => ....
)
```

Comment: This worked beautify for the QPP fixed length columns formats. I used `A` instead of `a` as it was space separated but thanks so much. This is the best answer I think.

Answer (score 3):

Just for future references the regular expressions method @jay suggested goes like this:

```
 $regex="/(.{1})(.{18})(.{32})(.{41})(.{108})(.{125})(.{137})(.{152})(.{161})/";
 preg_match($regex,$myfixedlengthstring,$arr);
```

where **$myfixedlengthstring** is the target string and **$arr** gives you the result

Answer (score 1):

A slightly more flexible variant, useful to parse ASCII tables with fixed-length records:

```
function ParseIrregularString  ($string, $lengths)
{ 
$parts = array(); 

foreach ($lengths as $StringKey => $position)
    { 
    $parts[$StringKey] = substr($string, 0, $position); 
    $string = substr($string, $position); 
    } 

return $parts; 
}
```

Submitting the following:

```
$string = "abcdefghiklmnopqrstuvz";
$lengths = array ("field1"=>4, "field2"=>3, "field3"=>5, "field4"=>2);
print_r (ParseIrregularString ($string, $lengths));
```

returns:

```
Array ( [field1] => abcd [field2] => efg [field3] => hiklm [field4] => no )
```