# str_split() with several length

Tags: php

I search something like str_split, but whidth several lenths. For example :

```
$str = "Hello Friend";
$arr1 = str_split_custom($str, array(2, 3, 7));
print_r($arr1);
```

and the resulte would be

```
Array
(
    [0] => He
    [1] => llo
    [2] =>  Friend
)
```

Comment: What exactly is your problem?

Comment: Are you looking for this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11382217/split-php-string-into-chunks-of-varying-length

Comment: Yes exactly thank you !